# Kafka: Does log.retention.bytes apply only to partition leader or also replicas?

Tags: apache-kafka, broker, retention

Does the byte retention policy apply to replica partitions or leader partitions or both?
In a multi-node cluster, with all brokers configured configured with different retention policies, it seems obvious that the partitions for which a given broker is a leader will be subject to the local byte retention policy, but what about the partitions for which the given broker is a replica? Are they subject to the same policy?

For example, a 2 node cluster with single topic and two partitions.

- Broker A is the leader for partition 1 and contains the replica of
  partition 2
- Broker B is the leader for partition 2 and contains the
  replica of partition 1
- Broker A has a byte retention policy of 1 byte
- Broker B has a byte retention policy of 2 bytes

Will broker A retain 1 byte of of both partitions it hosts?
Likewise, will broker B retain 2 bytes of both partitions it hosts?

Comment: why would you have different retention policy on different nodes in your cluster?

Comment: @AnilGupta , the original use case was for a cluster with heterogenous storage capacity, where we wanted to use 80% of _whatever_ the locally available disk was (using a convoluted calculation involving topic counts,partition counts, replication,etc) for Kafka storage. If the partition leader was on a bigger disk than that of the replica machine, it could cause issues. We've since re-written the log.retention.bytes such that it first determines the minimum disk  space available for a given node in the cluster, and sets the byte retention for all of the nodes in the cluster based on this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as per my cluster which contains 3 nodes it impact all the machine in cluster.

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 172.29.xx.xx:2181 --alter --topic topicname --config retention.ms=2100000
```